# Homotopy colimit,weighted colimit, homotopy theory

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, limits-colimits

Let's take the definition of $\mathbb{hocolim}$ as the representation of the representable functor like this:

$\underline{\cal M}(\mathbb {hocolim}_{ \cal D} F,m)\cong \mathrm {{sSet}^{\cal D^{op}}}(N(-/\cal D),\underline{\cal M}(F,m)) $,

using weighetd colimit weighted by the nerve of $\cal D$.My question is why
this object *must* be equipped with a ***universal simplicial natural transformation***

$N(d/\cal D)\Rightarrow \underline{\cal {M}}(Fd,\mathbb{hocolim}_{ \cal D} F)$. What information this n.t. gives to us and what it means universal?

For the definition of the data used in this post
 see [Riehl:Categorical Homotopy Theory,CUP 2014.](http://libgen.io/get_new.php?md5=9d11de78b1a6c96eb3a1703f5f58407e),page 117

Comment: Take $m = \operatorname{hocolim} F$ on the LHS. Then you have $\mathrm{id}$. Follow it across the bijection to get the desired universal simplicial natural transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is **yoneda lemma**.

The longer answer is the following.
By yoneda lemma we know that for every co-presheaf $P \colon \mathbf C \to \mathbf {Set}$ and every object $c \in \mathbf C$ there is a bijection 
$$\mathbf{Set}^C[\mathbf C[c,-],P]\cong P(c)$$
which is natural both in $c$ and $P$ (i.e. it is a natural transformation between the (bi)functors $\mathbf{Set}^\mathbf{C}[y_{-},-]$ and $\text{eval}$, the evaluation functor, objects of the category $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathbf C\times \mathbf{Set}^\mathbf C}$).

This natural isomorphism sends every natural isomorphism between $\mathbf C[c,-]$ and $P$ to an element in $P(c)$ which is universal for $P$ (take a look to any standard book in category theory for the details).

If you want to use the characterization of homotopy colimits as a representable objects you have to remember that in this case a homotopy colimit is not just an object: it is the data given by **an object**, namely $\text{hocolim} F \in \mathcal M$, **and a natural isomorphism between the functors $\mathcal M[\text{hocolim} F,-]$ and $\mathbf{sSet}^{\mathcal D^\text{op}}[N(-,/\mathcal D),\mathcal M[F,-]]$**.

By yoneda lemma this natural transformation can **encoded** as an element of $$\mathbf{sSet}^{\mathcal D^\text{op}}[N(-/\mathcal D),\mathcal M[F,\text{hocolim} F]]$$ 
that is a natural transformation $N(-/\mathcal D) \Rightarrow \mathcal M[F,\text{hocolim}F]$ and **this n.t. allows one to recover completely the isomorphism between the representable functor and the presheaf above**, so it completely determinate the representable object, hence the homotopy colimit.

Hope this fully address your doubts.
Feel free to ask if you need additional details or clarifications.